# Get a Array, remove some values of the objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to resolve this problem, I have a bunch of objects in my array, example:

```
[{
active: true
created: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.000Z"
description: {en: "Teste"}
id: "asd8180192580912"
modified: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.668Z"
price: 2313
restaurant: "5112125125sd"
title: {en: "Teste"}
}]
```

and I have another array with objects that is the selected one that got changed value of quantity like:

```
[{
active: true
created: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.000Z"
description: {en: "Teste"}
id: "asd8180192580912"
modified: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.668Z"
price: 2313
quantity: 10  // when I change the value of the counter
restaurant: "5112125125sd"
title: {en: "Teste"}
}]
```

the problem is that I need to pass only the 'quantity' and 'id' of the array, can u guys help me with some tips to create a new array with objects with this two arrays but with just the id and quantity? like this one:

```
   [
    {supplementId: "5f58079e2f5a16001d0fa276", quantity: 0}
    {supplementId: "5f86699d4124db828b00245a78af", quantity: 0}
    {supplement: "1233123151fasdf125", quantity: 7}]
```

update: Perhaps I need to push into the first array checking the Id if it is equal and create another array with just quantity and id.

update: I did a reduce like the comment bellow and this help me to finish the task, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. What's the problem with `x`?

Comment: Your current code works fine, it returns an array of object with only quantity and supplement.

Comment: @JoshBonnick but the last one is the main approach :P, I just created a random but I need to do something like that for real

Comment: Is your other Array of the same Objects or copies of those Objects? The later is probably unnecessary. If you get the Object located in the Array on some type of user action, just `.push` what you need onto an Array of supplements or iterate through the supplements Array to find the product you're looking for, get the correct Object and increment or decrement the `quantity` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map both arrays into array of objects using `Array.map`

```js
const objArr = [...arr1, ...arr2]
  .map((item) => ({ 
    supplementId: item.id,
    quantity: item.quantity
  }))
```

Or use `Array.reduce` to have more control over choosing what to do if you have same IDs in both arrays.

```js
const objs = [...arr1, ...arr2]
  .reduce((acc, item) => { 
    if (acc[item.id]) {
      acc[item.id] += item.quantity;
      return acc;
    }
    acc[item.id] = item.quantity;
    return acc;
  }, {});
const objArr = Object.keys(objs)
  .map((itemId) => ({
    supplementId: itemId,
    quantity: objs[itemId]
  }));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crude example of what you probably need to see:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
const supply = [
  {
    active: true,
    created: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.000Z",
    description: {en: "Teste"},
    id: "asd8180192580912",
    modified: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.668Z",
    price: 2313,
    restaurant: "5112125125sd",
    title: {en: "Teste"}
  },
  {
    active: true,
    created: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.000Z",
    description: {en: "Teste"},
    id: "number2",
    modified: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.668Z",
    price: 2,
    restaurant: "5112125125sd",
    title: {en: "Teste"}
  },
  {
    active: true,
    created: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.000Z",
    description: {en: "Teste"},
    id: "number3",
    modified: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.668Z",
    price: 3,
    restaurant: "5112125125sd",
    title: {en: "Teste"}
  },
  {
    active: true,
    created: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.000Z",
    description: {en: "Teste"},
    id: "number4",
    modified: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.668Z",
    price: 4,
    restaurant: "5112125125sd",
    title: {en: "Teste"}
  },
  {
    active: true,
    created: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.000Z",
    description: {en: "Teste"},
    id: "number5",
    modified: "2020-10-14T02:59:41.668Z",
    price: 5,
    restaurant: "5112125125sd",
    title: {en: "Teste"}
  }
];
const items = Q('.main>.items'), sups = [];
function getSup(id){
  for(let i=0,s,l=sups.length; i<l; i++){
    s = sups[i];
    if(s.id === id){
      return s;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
for(let z=0,i=0,n=1,p,m,it,l=items.length; i<l; z++,i+=2,n+=2){
  p = items[i]; m = items[n]; it = supply[z];
  p.onclick = ()=>{
    let s = getSup(it.id);
    if(s){
      s.quantity++;
    }
    else{
      it.quantity = 1; sups.push(it);
    }
    console.clear(); console.log(sups);
  }
  m.onclick = ()=>{
    let s = getSup(it.id);
    if(s){
      s.quantity--;
      if(s.quantity === 0)sups.splice(sups.indexOf(s), 1);
    }
    console.clear(); console.log(sups);
  }
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; font:22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden;
}
html,body,.main{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
.main{
  background:#333; overflow-y:auto; padding:10px;
}
.items{
  width:calc(50% - 3px); background:linear-gradient(#1b7bbb,#147); color:#fff; font:bold 28px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; padding:5px 10px;
  border:1px solid #005; border-radius:5px; cursor:pointer; float:left;
}
.items:nth-child(even){
  margin-left:6px;
}
.items:nth-child(n+3){
  margin-top:7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <input class='items' type='button' value='+ item 1' />
    <input class='items' type='button' value='- item 1' />
    <input class='items' type='button' value='+ item 2' />
    <input class='items' type='button' value='- item 2' />
    <input class='items' type='button' value='+ item 3' />
    <input class='items' type='button' value='- item 3' />
    <input class='items' type='button' value='+ item 4' />
    <input class='items' type='button' value='- item 4' />
    <input class='items' type='button' value='+ item 5' />
    <input class='items' type='button' value='- item 5' />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```